# NullPointerException JPA com springboot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

estou com um problema que acredito ser simples, porém estou com dificuldade para resolver.

Para ficar mais claro, vou resumir a ideia do projeto: Tenho uma classe Cliente e uma classe Atualização.

A classe atualização tem como atributo Cliente, onde é inserido no banco de dados uma nova atualização e vinculado ao cliente, a principio fiz o mapeamento ManyToOne e tento buscar o cliente de acordo com o CNPJ que vem via JSON na classe atualização, porém o código sempre retorno NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

Acontece que eu tenho o metodo na classe de serviço cliente e consigo buscar o cliente via CNPJ, e caso não tenha, ele retorna NULL e eu consigo comparar, se for NULO então CADASTRA o cliente... Somente quando o tento buscar direto da classe de Atualização retorno o NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

OBS: O erro ocorre ao tentar buscar o cliente pelo CNPJ na classe de servico ATUALIZACAO

**Segue abaixo o erro:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at projeto.KGClientes.clientes.service.AtualizacaoService.salvar(AtualizacaoService.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at projeto.KGClientes.clientes.service.AtualizacaoService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8cdb507.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at projeto.KGClientes.clientes.service.AtualizacaoService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$de74feec.salvar(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at projeto.KGClientes.clientes.controller.AtualizacaoController.atualizacao(AtualizacaoController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**Classe ATUALIZACAO**

```
package projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_Atualizacao")
public class Atualizacao{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence_id_atualizacao")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence_id_atualizacao", sequenceName = "sequence_id_atualizacao", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "IdAtualizacao")
    private Integer IdAtualizacao;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Cliente")
    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente Cliente;
        
    @Column(name = "Revisao")
    private String Revisao;

    @Column(name = "UltimaAtualizacao")
    private String Ultatuali;
    
    @Column(name = "DataVersao")
    private String Dataversao;
    
    @Column(name = "NomeVersao")
    private String Nomeversao;
    
    @Column(name = "DataCompilacao")
    private String Datacompilacao;
    
    @Column(name = "HoraCompilacao")
    private String Horacompilacao;
    
    @Column(name = "RevisaoIndiceTabelas")
    private String Revisaoindicestabelas;
    
    @Column(name = "CriadoEm")
    private String CriadoEm;
    
    //Tabela responsavel por armazenar o horario do arquivo 
    //Parame.ini, comando linux (stat -c %Y), caso o horario
    //gravado nesta variavel seja diferente do horario que o
    //script enviar, grava uma nova atualizacao.
    @Column(name = "Modificado")
    private String Modificado;
    
    public Atualizacao() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); //Padrão da data
        Date data = new Date(); 
        CriadoEm = sdf.format(data); //Converte a data para String
    }
    
    
    //---------GETTERS AND SETTERS-------------//

    public Integer getIdCliente() {
        return IdAtualizacao;
    }

    public void setIdCliente(Integer idCliente) {
        IdAtualizacao = idCliente;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return Cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        Cliente = cliente;
    }

    public String getRevisao() {
        return Revisao;
    }

    public void setRevisao(String revisao) {
        Revisao = revisao;
    }

    public String getUltatuali() {
        return Ultatuali;
    }

    public void setUltatuali(String ultatuali) {
        Ultatuali = ultatuali;
    }

    public String getDataversao() {
        return Dataversao;
    }

    public void setDataversao(String dataversao) {
        Dataversao = dataversao;
    }

    public String getNomeversao() {
        return Nomeversao;
    }

    public void setNomeversao(String nomeversao) {
        Nomeversao = nomeversao;
    }

    public String getDatacompilacao() {
        return Datacompilacao;
    }

    public void setDatacompilacao(String datacompilacao) {
        Datacompilacao = datacompilacao;
    }

    public String getHoracompilacao() {
        return Horacompilacao;
    }

    public void setHoracompilacao(String horacompilacao) {
        Horacompilacao = horacompilacao;
    }

    public String getRevisaoindicestabelas() {
        return Revisaoindicestabelas;
    }

    public void setRevisaoindicestabelas(String revisaoindicestabelas) {
        Revisaoindicestabelas = revisaoindicestabelas;
    }

    public String getCriadoEm() {
        return CriadoEm;
    }

    public void setCriadoEm(String criadoEm) {
        CriadoEm = criadoEm;
    }


    public Integer getIdAtualizacao() {
        return IdAtualizacao;
    }


    public void setIdAtualizacao(Integer idAtualizacao) {
        IdAtualizacao = idAtualizacao;
    }


    public String getModificado() {
        return Modificado;
    }


    public void setModificado(String modificado) {
        Modificado = modificado;
    }   
}
```

**Classe Service ATUALIZACAO**

```
package projeto.KGClientes.clientes.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.management.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity.Atualizacao;
import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity.Cliente;
import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.repository.AtualizacaoRepository;
import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.repository.ClienteRepository;



@Service
public class AtualizacaoService {

    @Autowired
    private AtualizacaoRepository atualizacaoRep;
    private ClienteService clienteServ;
    
    @Transactional
    public Atualizacao salvar(Atualizacao atualizacao) {
        //Localiza o cliente

atualizacao.setCliente(clienteServ.buscarClienteCNPJ("77962827000100"));**
*//O ERRO DE NULLPOINTER OCORRE NESTA LINHA, AO TENTAR LOCALIZAR O CLIENTE PELO CNPJ

        
        //Localiza se ja tem alguma atualizacao com o mesmo valor do campo "Modificado"
        Atualizacao a = atualizacaoRep.findByModificado(atualizacao.getModificado());
        
        //Grava o cliente encontrado com o CNPJ informado
        //atualizacao.setCliente(c);
        if(a.getModificado() == atualizacao.getModificado()) {
            //Essa atualizacao ja foi adicionada, exception
        }
        return atualizacaoRep.save(atualizacao);
    }
    
    public List<Atualizacao> listar() {
        return atualizacaoRep.findAll();    
    }
    
    public void excluir(Atualizacao cliente) {
        atualizacaoRep.delete(cliente);
    }
    
    public Atualizacao buscarPorId(Integer id) {
        return atualizacaoRep.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public void excluirPorId(Integer id) {
        atualizacaoRep.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**Classe SERVICE CLIENTE**

```
package projeto.KGClientes.clientes.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity.Atualizacao;
import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity.Cliente;
import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.repository.ClienteRepository;



@Service
public class ClienteService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRep;
    
    @Transactional
    public Cliente salvar(Cliente cliente) {
        //if(cliente.getCpf() != null) {
        //  BusinessExceptionCode codigoErro = BusinessExceptionCode.ERR001;
        //  BusinessException b = new BusinessException(codigoErro);
        //  throw b;
        //}
        Cliente c = buscarClienteCNPJ(cliente.getCnpj());
        if(!(c == null)){ //Ja cadastrado (nao nulo)
            //CLIENTE JA CADASTRADO, EXCEPTION
            return null;
        }
        
        return clienteRep.save(cliente);
        
    }
    
    public List<Cliente> listar() {
        return clienteRep.findAll();    
    }
    
    public void excluir(Cliente cliente) {
        clienteRep.delete(cliente);
    }
    
    public Cliente buscarPorId(Integer id) {
        return clienteRep.findById(id).get();
    }
    
    public Cliente buscarClienteCNPJ(String cnpj) { //Busca exata, deve ter o cnpj completo
        return clienteRep.findByCnpj(cnpj);
    }
}
```

**E por ultimo, classe REPOSITORY do Cliente:**

```
package projeto.KGClientes.clientes.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import projeto.KGClientes.clientes.entity.Cliente;

public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente c where c.cnpj = :cnpj", nativeQuery = true)
    public Cliente findByCnpj(@Param("cnpj") String cnpj);
    
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente c where c.idCliente = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Cliente findByIdCliente(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um `@Autowired` no `ClienteService`:

```
@Service
public class AtualizacaoService {

    @Autowired
    private AtualizacaoRepository atualizacaoRep;
    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteServ;
    
    @Transactional
    public Atualizacao salvar(Atualizacao atualizacao) {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Faltou um @Autowired no ClienteService:

```
@Service
public class AtualizacaoService {

    @Autowired
    private AtualizacaoRepository atualizacaoRep;
    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteServ;
    
    @Transactional
    public Atualizacao salvar(Atualizacao atualizacao) {
     ...
    }
```

E faltou um @Repository na interface ClienteRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente c where c.cnpj = :cnpj", nativeQuery = true)
    public Cliente findByCnpj(@Param("cnpj") String cnpj);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tb_cliente c where c.idCliente = :id", nativeQuery = true)
    public Cliente findByIdCliente(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

desta forma deverá funcionar.

Comment: Olá Rafael, não foi o mesmo que o [@Nullprt respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/464508/3635)? O que difere as duas respostas?

Comment: A diferença é que complementei com a anotação que faltou no Repository, sei que o comentário dele está certo, mas também faltou esta anotação, e para não correr o risco de alguém só ver o meu comentário e anotar só o @Repository, peguei o comentário dele e complementei com o que vi que faltou.
não estou querendo ganhar pontos copiando respostas alheias, só pensei que existe uma chance de não verem ambos os comentários.
Se me compreende, coloca que minha resposta é util.

Comment: Ok, -1 removido. Ninguém lhe acusou de querer ganhar pontos, o que não tinha ficado claro é aonde que estava diferente, mas agora ficou esclarecido. Seja bem vindo.